# Smart Language Switching in Windows 10 keyboard

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, typing

I have three languages installed, but I mainly use only 2 of them. As a result, I have to press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>Left ALT</kbd> twice sometimes to switch between my two main languages, which can get pretty irritating.

Is there a way to "turn off" the third language until I need to use it?

Alternatively, my Android keyboard switches to the last language used instead of a fixed ordering, similar to how windows prioritizes applications when pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>. Is there a way to have that on windows?

Solutions that work but are not ideal:

1. Defining a different shortcut for every language. This isn't ideal because <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> is very intuitive and my go-to.
2. Removing the third language. This means that every time I want to use it I need to install it again, which is way too much work.